# Converting .jar to .exe

Tags: java, compilation, launch4j

I created a project that needs to add mail.jar to Classpath ... so I did it and everything after running in the IDE works ... a

After I tried using launch4j to compile an .exe file with custom classpath I got this output:

```
    Executing: C:\Users\resti\Desktop\tic-tac-toe.exe
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
    at mail.FileListing.Listuj(FileListing.java:54)
    at mail.GUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(GUI.java:147)
    at mail.GUI.access$000(GUI.java:16)
    at mail.GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:51)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

So I deduced that there is an error when adding classpath in the build process, despite the fact that classpath is set, someone should not tip how to fix it

-- PLS ignore project name --

[image: here is custom classpath screenshot]

Comment: why would you want to turn a jar into an exe?

Comment: @Stultuske So the application can be treated as a native executable...?

Comment: @Slaw if one needs that, why use java?

Comment: @Stultuske Because you can still write the same cross-platform code, you just deploy it natively. For instance, `jpackage` is capable of creating self-contained (i.e. embedded JRE) native executables/installers for Windows, Mac, and Linux. There's also Launch4J, as mentioned in the question, which has been around for a while. And there's also GraalVM which is capable of ahead-of-time compilation. But in each case the code is still written in Java. Note this tends to only makes sense for desktop applications (e.g. AWT, Swing, JavaFX, console-based, etc.), not web applications.